# script files are not calling in porto theme in magento2.2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I created multi website in my website.

Main website is working fine. But, second website is not working.

Main website:https://www.depoto.com/

Sub website:http://multistore.depoto.com/

[image: http://multistore.depoto.com/]

Comment: Did you tried `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command from your terminal?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI check once my updated question

Comment: ok abishek I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

We have Two method to solve

method 1

Define your parent theme.xml file .So parent theme able to access responsive.js and theme.js file

```
app/design/frontend/Thomson/Book/theme.xml

<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Multistore</title> 
   <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- parent theme -->
   <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>
</theme>
```

method 2

Add responsive.js and theme.js files in  custom theme.

Like

```
> multistore
>     └── depoto
>         └── theme.xml
>         |-- web
>              |--js
>                  |--responsive.js
>                  |--theme.js
```